# Populating Gridview inside Listview ItemTemplate On Web User Control from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

I have what I think is a simple question, however it might be more complex..

I have spent a few days looking for the answer on google and various questions on this site but cannot seem to come right.

What I am trying to do is to bind to a Gridview on the User Control ascx page from the Default.aspx.cs on the Page Load event.

User Control markup is as follows:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VulnerabilityExternalIP.ascx.cs" Inherits="VulnerabilityAssesment.Controls.VulnerabilityExternalIP" %>

<asp:Table runat="server" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="2">
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityName" runat="server" Text="Vulnerability Name:" CssClass="itemName"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityNameText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MainVulnerabilityName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityCategory" runat="server" Text="Category:" CssClass="itemName"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityCategoryText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Category") %>'></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityPopularity" runat="server" Text="Popularity:" CssClass="itemName"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityPopularityText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Popularity") %>'></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="lblVulnerabilityRisk" runat="server" Text="Risk:" CssClass="itemName"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="blVulnerabilityRiskText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RiskFactor") %>'></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
    <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblHostsAffected" runat="server" Text="Hosts Affected:" CssClass="itemName"></asp:Label>
<br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHostsAffected" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="700px" ReadOnly="true" BroderWidth="0px" Text='<%# Eval("HostNamePort") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:GridView ID="gvHostsAffected" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

I am referencing the User Control on the Default.aspx as follows:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/VulnerabilityExternalIP.ascx" TagName="VulnerabilityExternalIP" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

Within the default.asxp I have the following defined:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="lvVulnerabilityExternalIP" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <uc1:VulnerabilityExternalIP Template="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" ID="vulnerabilityExtIP" name="vulnext" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</asp:Content>
```

The code behind on Default.aspx.cs is as follows:

```
namespace VulnerabilityAssesment
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string HostNamePort = "";
        string VulnerabilityDesc = "";
        string VulnerabilitySummary = "";
        string VulnerabilitySolution = "";
        string VulnerabilityCVE = "";
        string VulnerbilityLink = "";

       // Use connection string from Web.Config

        string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csVulnerabilityAssesment"].ConnectionString;

        //Create new SQL Connection

       SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        //Create Stored Procedure Command and Declare Parameters

       SqlCommand vulnerabilityHeader = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[_spGet_VulnerabilityHeader]", conn);
        vulnerabilityHeader.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        vulnerabilityHeader.Parameters.Add("@VulnerabilityReport", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "External IP Ranges";

        //Create Data Adapter and Data Set

        SqlDataAdapter sdaVulnerabilityHeader = new SqlDataAdapter(vulnerabilityHeader);
        DataSet dsVulnerabilityHeader = new DataSet();

        //Open Connection

        conn.Open();

        //Fill Data Adapter

        sdaVulnerabilityHeader.Fill(dsVulnerabilityHeader);

        //Fill in template

        List<VulnerabilityTemplate> Template = new List<VulnerabilityTemplate>();

        if (dsVulnerabilityHeader.Tables != null)
            if (dsVulnerabilityHeader.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            if (dsVulnerabilityHeader.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dsVulnerabilityHeader.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                    string GroupID = dr["GroupSequence"].ToString();

                    //Declare Stored Procedue for Vulnerability Details and set Parameters


                   SqlCommand vulnerabilityDetail = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[_spGet_VulnerabilityDetail]", conn);
                    vulnerabilityDetail.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    vulnerabilityDetail.Parameters.Add("@VulnerabilityReport", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "External IP Ranges";
                    vulnerabilityDetail.Parameters.Add("@GroupSequence", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GroupID;

                   // Declare SQL Data Adapter for Vulnerability Detail

                   SqlDataAdapter sdaVulnerabilityDetail = new SqlDataAdapter(vulnerabilityDetail);
                    DataSet dsVulnerabilityDetail = new DataSet();

                   // Fill Data Adapter

                    sdaVulnerabilityDetail.Fill(dsVulnerabilityDetail);

                   // Declare Stored Procedure for Vulnerability Summary and Set Paramters


                   SqlCommand vulnerabilitySummary = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[_spGet_VulnerabilitySummary]", conn);
                    vulnerabilitySummary.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    vulnerabilitySummary.Parameters.Add("@VulnerabilityReport", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "External IP Ranges";
                    vulnerabilitySummary.Parameters.Add("@GroupSequence", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GroupID;

                   // Declare SQL Data Adapter for Vulnerability Detail

                   SqlDataAdapter sdaVulnerabilitySummary = new SqlDataAdapter(vulnerabilitySummary);
                    DataSet dsVulnerabilitySummary = new DataSet();

                   // Fill Data Adapter

                    sdaVulnerabilityDetail.Fill(dsVulnerabilityDetail);
                    sdaVulnerabilitySummary.Fill(dsVulnerabilitySummary);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dsVulnerabilityDetail.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (HostNamePort != "")
                            HostNamePort += Environment.NewLine;

                        HostNamePort += row["HostnamePort"].ToString();
                    }

                    foreach (DataRow vulnerabilitySummaryRow in dsVulnerabilitySummary.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        VulnerabilityDesc += vulnerabilitySummaryRow["VulnerabilityDesc"].ToString();
                        VulnerabilitySummary += vulnerabilitySummaryRow["VulnerabilitySummary"].ToString();
                        VulnerabilitySolution += vulnerabilitySummaryRow["VulnerabilitySolution"].ToString();
                    }

                    //myGrid.DataSource = dsVulnerabilityDetail.Tables[0];
                    //GridView myGrid = (GridView)lvVulnerabilityExternalIP.Items.FindControl("gvHostsAffected");

                    // Always returns null :(

                    GridView myGrid = (GridView)lvVulnerabilityExternalIP.FindControl("gvHostsAffected");



                    Template.Add(new VulnerabilityTemplate
                    {
                        MainVulnerabilityName = dr["MainVulnerabilityName"].ToString(),
                        Category = dr["Category"].ToString(),
                        Popularity = dr["Popularity"].ToString(),
                        Riskfactor = dr["RiskFactor"].ToString(),
                        HostNamePort = HostNamePort
                        //VulnerabilityDesc = VulnerabilityDesc,
                        //VulnerabilitySolution = VulnerabilitySolution,
                        //VulnerabilitySummary = VulnerabilitySummary



                    }
                     );

                    myGrid.DataBind();
                }
            }

        lvVulnerabilityExternalIP.DataSource = Template;
        lvVulnerabilityExternalIP.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
    }


    // Below Does not work

    protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            DataTable table = (DataTable)e.Item.DataItem;
            GridView myGrid = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvHostsAffected");
            myGrid.DataSource = table;
            myGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
}
```

I cannot seem to find the gvHostsAffected grid view to bind it to the dsVulnerabilityDetail.Tables[0] value (which should be a single column called HostsAffected, this result could return 1 or more rows.

I have included two things that I have tried denoted by the comment //Below does not work.

The Template.Add method does work and it populates necessary information on the user control.

Is there any way I can find the Gridview control during the iteration and populate it with the results from the dsVulnerabilityDetail data set?

Thank you in advance.

Update 10 April 2017

Below is the Code Behind for the WebControl, I see I forgot to include it in the original Question.

```
    namespace VulnerabilityAssesment.Controls
{
public partial class VulnerabilityExternalIP : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public GridView myGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return gvHostsAffected;
        }
        set
        {
           gvHostsAffected = value;
        }
    }


}
```

}

The markup for Web Control include the answer by VDWWD.

Comment: You probably forgot to include the markup of your control

Comment: I did, thanks. will include.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a public `GridView` property to the User Control

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public GridView myGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return GridView1;
        }
        set
        {
            GridView1 = value;
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Then you can access it like yo would a GridView on the same page. The only thing left to do is to use `FindControl` to find the User Control inside the `ListView`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebUserControl1 control = lvVulnerabilityExternalIP.Items[2].FindControl("vulnerabilityExtIP") as WebUserControl1;
    control.myGridView.DataSource = mySource;
    control.myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi VDWWD, I have added the partial class but cannot access it on the Page_load event? I have taken the following from the protected void Button1_Click event:

WebUserControl1 control = lvVulnerabilityExternalIP.Items[2].FindControl("vulnerabilityExtIP") as WebUserControl1;

I have changed WebUsercontrol1 and am trying to replace it with VulnerabilityExternalIP as this is the partial class from the ascx file.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be it. Just like `_Default` is the name of the normal page in your snippet.

Comment: HI, ok, so I added the using VulnerabilityAssesment.Controls; declaration to the Default.aspx.cs page and can now reference VulnerabilityExternalIP, however it during the page load event it tells me that the "Index was out of range, Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. The control value is NULL. Am I missing something?